# Hiding the Code in .CDF File

Tags: cdf-format

I downloaded the source code of a demonstration and modified it. Then saved it as a CDF file. When I re-opened this file (in *Mathematica* or *CDF Player*), all of the code can be seen. How can I hide the code so that only the manipulation panel be shown? I want it to be seen just as the demonstrations on the website demonstration.wolfram.com.

I searched this site but found no solution to my problem. By the way, I use *Mathematica* 8.0.

Comment: Try this: Select the cell with the code you want to hide, then select Cell > Cell Properties. Click on Open to uncheck it.

Comment: Did what m_goldberg said above help you?

Comment: @Öskå Well, the result was not exactly what I wanted; the closed cells are still visible. However the code is hidden.

Comment: Well, since the question was "Hiding the Code in .cdf file" I guess the fact that the code is now hidden answered the question ;o)

Comment: @m_goldberg Answer?

Comment: This is answered here also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150970/how-can-i-include-an-interactive-cdf-in-a-latex-document  `If you do not want to display the code and any other cells other than the display, then select the cells you want to hide and do cell->cell properties ->open to flip it to close. Now all cells are closed other than the display Manipulate cells and any other you did not select to close.`

Comment: How to change the author codes in cdf player.??

Answer (score 6):

Try this: select the cell with the code you want to hide, then select **Cell > Cell Properties**. Click on **Open** to uncheck it.

The code will be hidden, but a skinny, residual, empty cell will remain. If there were no residual cell, there would no way to reopen the cell should that became necessary.

Comment: I am looking for an answer to the same question. Is this the way they use in the demonstrations @Behzad mentioned? 

By the way, the option Cell > Cell Properties > Editable should be also unchecked, or isn't it necessary when creating CDF documents?